# Mysql: Multiple Row Compare

Tags: mysql

From this Mysql-table:

```
Attributes
Brand   |attr   |   vals
Samsung | RAM   |   '750'
Samsung | CPU   |   '1200'
HTC     | RAM   |   '1000'
HTC     | CPU   |   '1500'
```

i don't know how to get all items with

```
RAM>500
CPU>1300
```

As Result i just need the brands which matches all Parameters:

```
Attributes
Brand   |attr   |   vals
HTC     | *     |   *
```

SEE the SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/491d7/1

Comment: Is `vals` a `VARCHAR` field? Can it contain non-numeric values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would get the result by pivoting the data:

```
select brand, RAM, CPU
from
(
   select brand,
      max(case when attr='RAM' then cast(vals as unsigned) end) as RAM,
      max(case when attr='CPU' then cast(vals as unsigned) end) as CPU
   from attributes
   group by brand
) d
where RAM > 500
  and CPU > 1300
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/491d7/25)

Comment: Yo, thats the best Result and ergonomy is great. That works also fine with >1.000.000 Rows + ORDER BY option! other SQLs here are more than 60 Seconds with an "ORDER" Statement- txs!

Comment: @dazzafact how long does it take for >1'000'000 rows + order by?

Comment: @agim I have no idea how long it will take a query to run in your database.

Comment: @bluefeet the query was meant for dazzafact. I thought he has a database with the data..

Comment: @agim somewhere between 1 second (a very powerful server) and an hour (my home laptop). Yours might be in between.

Comment: Looking at the query plan in sql fiddle, I was wondering if this query would perform better, if you use `having RAM > 500 and CPU > 130` instead of using a subquery..

Comment: @agim I do not use a having clause unless I am using an aggregate function to filter.

Comment: @bluefeet why not? The query plan using a having clause looks better.

Comment: @agim: because it wouldn't be a valid SQL query. Even MySQL wouldn't allow it in a server with strict ANSI settings.

Comment: @ypercube, but in this case you are using an aggregate function to filter and of cause it would be a valid SQL query. I posted the modified query so you can try it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The outermost WHERE clause first qualifies on the RAM attribute of 1300 or more.  By joining to itself again (alias "b") by the same brand, you now have same brand, but this time you are additionally qualifying the "b" attribute only on the CPU and it's value >= 500.  You could keep chaining additional JOINs on any other criteria.  This is doing a qualifier on ALL components you are looking for...

```
select
      a.Brand,
      a.vals as RAM,
      b.vals as CPU
   from
      Attributes a
         JOIN Attributes b
            on a.Brand = b.Brand
           AND b.attr = 'CPU'
           AND b.vals >= 1300
   where
          a.attr = 'RAM'
      AND a.vals >= 500
```

Comment: The query is OK, @DRapp missed to cast the `vals`

Comment: @dazzafact, sorry, you must have been between my post, I had the values swapped.. the CPU should be comparing to 1300 and RAM to 500, I originally had swapped and thus no records returned.

Comment: No, performance with 1.000.000 ROWs and an Order Statement. but tnx

Comment: @DRapp I'm not sure if the `vals >= 500` will do an integer comparison or a char comparison.

Comment: @ypercube, when I was looking at the details, it will do an implied conversion for you from string to numeric without the explicit (CAST) call.  The query does actually work.

Comment: This is probably the most efficient and would be even better if only the `vals` column had a numeric datatype so no casting were done and indexes could be used.

Comment: @ypercube, I agree, but actually BlueFeet's answer ran in 1ms, my version ran in 2ms via SQLFiddle.  With larger data sets, my version would immediately start with one qualifier instead of ALL possible items, then join to the rest.  Anyhow, always good to see alternate solutions by good-thinking minds... :)

Comment: Proper datatypes would also avoid this kind of problems: **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d254/3)**

Comment: @ypercube, yeah, but then you get thrown a property of 'COLOR' for a computer case and that throws a loop into the structure (yes, could be enumerated, but that too would not necessarily qualify all conditions) :(

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    Brand
FROM Attributes
WHERE
    (attr = 'RAM' AND cast(vals as unsigned) > 500)
    OR (attr = 'CPU' AND cast(vals as unsigned) > 1300)
GROUP BY Brand
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Yo, thats the best performance with 1.000.000 Rows with ORDER BY OPTION(cant beleave!)!! All other SQLs here are more than 300 Seconds with an ORDER Statement- tahnks!

Answer (score 1):

Changing @bluefeet's query so there is no derived table. It will probably improve efficiency in some MySQL versions but it will break ANSI/ISO SQL validness and it will not run with [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode:

```
select brand,
  max(case when attr='RAM' then cast(vals as unsigned) end) as RAM,
  max(case when attr='CPU' then cast(vals as unsigned) end) as CPU
from attributes
group by brand  
having RAM > 500
   and CPU > 1300 ;
```

Improving it, so it's valid, too:

```
select brand,
  max(case when attr='RAM' then cast(vals as unsigned) end) as RAM,
  max(case when attr='CPU' then cast(vals as unsigned) end) as CPU
from attributes
group by brand  
having max(case when attr='RAM' then cast(vals as unsigned) end) > 500
   and max(case when attr='CPU' then cast(vals as unsigned) end) > 1300 ;
```

Comment: I'll edit your answer, if you don't mind. The comment space is too small for this conversation. Rollback if you don't like the edit.

Comment: @ypercube ok I understand what you mean. I wasn't sure either of using `having RAM>...` but since it worked, I thought it would be ANSI standard ;)